# Using a reserved word (Type name) as ExpandoObject or Dynamic property

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, dynamic, expandoobject

How can I possibly set a property of an ExpandoObject with a key that is a reserved word?

Like this:

```
dynamic query = new ExpandoObject();
query.size = 10;
query.date = "2017-04-27";

dynamic match = new {
  query = query,
  bool = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In `ExpandoObject` you may use *any string value* as a property name (including reserved words, spaces, etc., even empty string) via casting the `ExpandoObject` instance to `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
dynamic query = new ExpandoObject();
(query as IDictionary<string, object>)["bool"] = true;
(query as IDictionary<string, object>)[" b o o (g)? l \"e:)\""] = false;
(query as IDictionary<string, object>)[""] = true;
```

**but** you won't be able to access such properties using "plain C# syntax" (i.e. `obj.prop`). You'd have to cast the object to `IDictionary<string, object>` and access them using indexer:

```
var qDict = query as IDictionary<string, object>;
Console.WriteLine(qDict["bool"]);
Console.WriteLine(qDict[" b o o (g)? l \"e:)\""]);
Console.WriteLine(qDict[""]);
// Prints:
//   True
//   False
//   True
```